# Rendering problems when choosing Holo Light theme

Tags: android, android-studio

I am studying android and I am having some error on the rendering part. Whenever I choose Holo Light or Material Light I always got a render error. But when I choose Apptheme its fine.

I am using API 23.

*Here's some screenshots:*

**The first is when I try to run using AppTheme**

[image]

**Then next is using the Holo Light**

[image]

**Different API (API 21) with Holo Light**

[image]

Can you help me with this? I am studying the **Action bar** and it using HoloLight.

Comment: Refer here to fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: I try to modify but still same effects. :(